# How to verify that C#/.NET COM object is actually a COM object?

Tags: c#, com

I have a C# project that creates a COM object for use with a POS terminal. Before I give it to the customer, I want to make sure that it will work as a COM dll. The RegAsm says it works.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace POS
{
    [Guid( "0135bc5c-b248-444c-94b9-b0b4577f5a1a" )]
    [InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual )]
    [ComVisible( true )]
    public interface ITwoWay
    {
        // The Initialize method is called to establish the communications connection...
        [DispId( 1 )]
        void Initialize( String IPAddress, long Port, long MaxPacketSize );

        // A convenience method that allows the POS to test the Third Party’s back-end...
        [DispId( 2 )]
        void TestConnect();

        // The Terminate method is called to indicate that the POS system is about to terminate...
        [DispId( 3 )]
        void Terminate();

        // All interface calls made during a transaction send the same record format with specific reply fields ...
        [DispId( 4 )]
        void TransactionCall( String viPOSMsg, ref String InterceptArray );
    }
}
```

The actual entry points are defined in class TwoWay

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.EnterpriseServices;

namespace POS
{
    [Guid( "0135bc5c-b248-444c-94b9-b0b4577f5a1b" )]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITwoWay))]
    [ClassInterface( ClassInterfaceType.None )]
    [ComVisible( true )]
    public class TwoWay : ITwoWay
    ...
    [ComVisible( true )]
    public void Initialize( string iPAddress, long port, long maxPacketSize )
    ...
```

I had thought that I could import the .tlb into another .net project and test it that way but when I add my COM project as a COM reference VS rejects it because it was created as .NET dll.

I tried to create a vb script to run CreateObject but that errors on permissions. I attempted to set up the I_USER account, etc but I couldn't get that going.

The registry shows an entry with the right name and the class id is set to the correct guid. But still, I want to load it and run it through the COM interface.

How does one verify that a COM .dll is actually a COM .dll? As old as this is, there must be a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick way of doing it is to use the [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) feature of .NET which is very useful for COM programming

So if you class is defined like this (I don't personally use COM interfaces with .NET, but that changes nothing if the interface is dual), note I've added a progid which is good COM practise:

```
[Guid("0135bc5c-b248-444c-94b9-b0b4577f5a1a")]
[ProgId("MyComponent.TwoWay")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class TwoWay
{
    public void Initialize(string IPAddress, long Port, long MaxPacketSize)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IPAddress);
    }

    // other methods...
}
```

Then I can test it using .NET like this (no need to create a TLB, just register it using regasm):

```
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyComponent.TwoWay");
dynamic twoway = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

twoway.Initialize("hello", 0, 0);
```

The inconvenient is you don't have auto completion, you just have to take care to pass arguments that fit. And .NET is smart enough to convert `Int32` into `Int64` (note the C# `long` you use is 64-bit wide).